# Yii filter option with exact value

Tags: php, filter, yii

i have a gridview with search option by a database table.All working fine but  the problem is when i enter a id value to search my grid it shows all the related value rows. For example if i enter value "1" it filters all 1's like 1,10,11,12,13,....
But i need to show only exact value what i entered it should show only the corresponding row i hope u understand my prob...

my model is like below

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array('order'=>'proc_id DESC'));
    //$criteria->condition = " status = 'Active' ";
    $criteria->compare('proc_id',$this->proc_id);
    $criteria->compare('book_id',$this->book_id,true);return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>50
    ),
    ));
}
```

hi i found the answer for my problem i just removed true from my code as below

```
        $criteria->compare('book_id',$this->book_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up any kind of mySql WHERE [condition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail) you want like this:

```
$criteria->addCondition('proc_id = :procid'); // add your sql WHERE condition
$criteria->params[':procid'] = $this->proc_id; // bind your parameter
```

You *should* be able to use [compare()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail) though, but you might have to cast the ID to an integer:

```
$criteria->compare('proc_id', (int) $this->proc_id);
```

Comment: thanks dude..this what i need but not exactly..from your code i  got the answer what i need the new problem is in default its not showing grid view just showing search option not values.pls help in this prob